# Copy nested Amazon S3 folders into flattened folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Long story short, we have documents stored something like this `/accounts/account-abc/docs/uuid.pdf` which is pretty redundant. What we want is basically `docs/uuid.pdf`. There are lots of other posts about copying, but they are all single dirs. I need something like this (which is obviously wrong):

```sh
aws s3 cp s3://accounts/*/docs s3://docs/  --recursive ---include "*"
```

Would I need to write a custom script in order to acomplish the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a Python script that will copy files from a given `SOURCE_PATH` to a `TARGET_PATH`, removing all sub-folders:

```py
import boto3

SOURCE_BUCKET = 'source-bucket'
SOURCE_PATH = 'accounts/'

TARGET_BUCKET = 'target-bucket'
TARGET_PATH = 'docs/'

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(SOURCE_BUCKET)

for object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=SOURCE_PATH):
    target_key = object.key[object.key.rfind('/')+1:]
    print('Copying', target_key)
    s3_resource.Object(TARGET_BUCKET, TARGET_PATH + target_key).copy({'Bucket':SOURCE_BUCKET, 'Key': object.key})
    # Optional, to delete source object:
    # object.delete()
```

You might need to modify it if you only wish to copy from a `SOURCE_PATH` that also contains a sub-directory of `docs` (based on your example).

Comment: thanks for this, I'm using go at the moment so will write a version using that and your example. Thanks again!